# Swift 2.1 equivalent of javascript Date.now()

Tags: javascript, swift2, nsdate

I'm looking for a Swift 2.1 equivalent of Date.now() in Javascript

example (in javascript)

```
Date.now()
>1454523253639
```

I tried with some NSDate() solutions but I was unable to find the right one

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Comment: [I think you're looking for this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` is `Double` in second.

`Date.now()` is unsigned integer in millisecond.

so:

```
let unixTimestamp = UInt(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)
NSLog("\(unixTimestamp)")
```

Comment: I Found another solution some minutes ago, but yours is totally better and more clean!

just to let you know, the other was

func currentTimeMillis() -> Int64{
    let nowDouble = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int64(nowDouble*1000)
}